# How to generate letters in salesforce

Tags: email-template, mail-merge

how to generate letters in salesforce from templates, and then to print via some button (print button).
I am in confusion about this. As I am confused in merge mail and generating letters.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Read about [Salesforce Mail Merge](http://eu1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/admin_mergetemplates.htm).

If your question is about [Email Templates , you can read here](https://eu1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/admin_emailtemplates.htm).

There is extensive documentation on how to create and use.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a visual force page which renders as PDF and generates a letter. It's straightforward to print a PDF.